# How can I resize an image when downloading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, resize, download

I want to resize my image when I am downloading it, or after download. This is my code. Quality is not important.

```
public void downloadPicture(string fileName, string url,string path) {
        string fullPath = string.Empty;
        fullPath = path + @"\" + fileName + ".jpg"; //imagePath
        byte[] content;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
            content = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            br.Close();
        }
        response.Close();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create); // Starting create
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        try {
            bw.Write(content); // Created
        }
        finally {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this code after the try / finally block -

This will resize the image to 1/4 its original size.

```
        using (System.Drawing.Image original = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath))
        {
            int newHeight = original.Height / 4;
            int newWidth = original.Width / 4;

            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap newPic = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newPic))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, (newWidth), (newHeight));
                    string newFilename = ""; /* Put new file path here */
                    newPic.Save(newFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can of course change it to any size you want, by changing the newHeight and newWidth variables

**UPDATE:** modified code to use using() {} instead of dispose, as per comment below.

Comment: fullPath = path + @"\" + fileName + "RESIZE.jpg"; string newFilename = fullPath.Replace("RESIZE",""); File.Delete(fullPath); I add them, and it works great. Thanks

Comment: -1 for not using `using(){}`, GDI operations can fail arbitrarily and leave you with a memory leak, which will in turn trigger more exceptions and additional leaked memory until the server crashes. The .NET GC is *not* aware of GDI objects like Image, Graphics, or Bitmap. They allocate dozens of megabytes of RAM in the unmanaged heap, invisible to .NET. A 500KB 12MP image requires 48MB of contiguous RAM to simply be decoded.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Agree, thanks for the heads up, modified code for future google reference :)

Answer (score 7):

Image resizing seems very simple on surface but involves many complication once start working on it. I would suggest don't do it by your self and use a decent library.

You can use [Image Resizer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx), its very an easy, open source and free library.

You can install it using Nuget or [download](http://downloads.imageresizing.net/Resizer3-1-5-full-Feb-22-2012.zip).

[image: Installing using nuget]

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings {
  MaxWidth = thumbnailSize,
  MaxHeight = thumbnailSize,
  Format = "jpg"
};

ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inStream, outStream, settings);
resized = outStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Image.FromFile(String)` to get an `Image` object and this site [Image Resizing](http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/06/image-resizing/) has an extensions methods to actually resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

In the application I made it was necessary to create a function with multiple options. It's quite large, but it resizes the image, can keep the aspect ratio and can cut of the edges to return only the center of the image:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Resize image with an URL as source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OriginalFileURL">Link to the image</param>
    /// <param name="heigth">new height</param>
    /// <param name="width">new width</param>
    /// <param name="keepAspectRatio">keep the aspect ratio</param>
    /// <param name="getCenter">return the center bit of the image</param>
    /// <returns>image with new dimentions</returns>
    public Image resizeImageFromURL(String OriginalFileURL, int heigth, int width, Boolean keepAspectRatio, Boolean getCenter)
    {
        int newheigth = heigth;
        WebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(OriginalFileURL);
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch
        {
            return (System.Drawing.Image) new Bitmap(1, 1);
        }
        Stream imageStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream);

        // Prevent using images internal thumbnail
        FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

        if (keepAspectRatio || getCenter)
        {
            int bmpY = 0;
            double resize = (double)FullsizeImage.Width / (double)width;//get the resize vector
            if (getCenter)
            {
                bmpY = (int)((FullsizeImage.Height - (heigth * resize)) / 2);// gives the Y value of the part that will be cut off, to show only the part in the center
                Rectangle section = new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, bmpY), new System.Drawing.Size(FullsizeImage.Width, (int)(heigth * resize)));// create the section to cut of the original image
                Bitmap orImg = new Bitmap((Bitmap)FullsizeImage);//for the correct effect convert image to bitmap.
                FullsizeImage.Dispose();//clear the original image
                using (Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height))
                {
                    Graphics cutImg = Graphics.FromImage(tempImg);//              set the file to save the new image to.
                    cutImg.DrawImage(orImg, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);// cut the image and save it to tempImg
                    FullsizeImage = tempImg;//save the tempImg as FullsizeImage for resizing later
                    orImg.Dispose();
                    cutImg.Dispose();
                    return FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, heigth, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
            else newheigth = (int)(FullsizeImage.Height / resize);//  set the new heigth of the current image
        }//return the image resized to the given heigth and width
        return FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, newheigth, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

To make it easier to acces the function it's possible to add some overloaded functions:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Resize image with an URL as source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OriginalFileURL">Link to the image</param>
    /// <param name="heigth">new height</param>
    /// <param name="width">new width</param>
    /// <returns>image with new dimentions</returns>
    public Image resizeImageFromURL(String OriginalFileURL, int heigth, int width)
    {
        return resizeImageFromURL(OriginalFileURL, heigth, width, false, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resize image with an URL as source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OriginalFileURL">Link to the image</param>
    /// <param name="heigth">new height</param>
    /// <param name="width">new width</param>
    /// <param name="keepAspectRatio">keep the aspect ratio</param>
    /// <returns>image with new dimentions</returns>
    public Image resizeImageFromURL(String OriginalFileURL, int heigth, int width, Boolean keepAspectRatio)
    {
        return resizeImageFromURL(OriginalFileURL, heigth, width, keepAspectRatio, false);
    }
```

Now are the last two booleans optional to set. Call the function like this:

```
System.Drawing.Image ResizedImage = resizeImageFromURL(LinkToPicture, 800, 400, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question some days back and i was directed to this thread, but really my own case is that i wanted to resize a bitmapImage. What i mean is that, you can convert the downloaded stream to bitmapImage and then resize, aspect ratio will still be maintained if you only specify either a width or height i.e

```
public static async void DownloadImagesAsync(BitmapImage list, String Url)
{
   try
   {
       HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
       // Limit the max buffer size for the response so we don't get overwhelmed
       httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
       httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE           10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
       HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Url);
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       byte[] str = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
       InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
       DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
       writer.WriteBytes(str);
       await writer.StoreAsync();
       BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
       img.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
       //img.DecodePixelHeight = 92;
       img.DecodePixelWidth = 60; //specify only width, aspect ratio maintained
       list.ImageBitmap = img;                   
   }catch(Exception e){
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
   }
}
```

from [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx)